# copy and past code with tab characters into vim

Tags: vim, tabs

I want to be able to copy and paste code into a file I am editing with vim and have vim paste tab characters instead of multiple space characters.

I have tried

```
:set noexpandtab
:set paste
:set noai
```

And I'm still pasting my code with the tab characters turning into single space characters

Example:
When I copy and paste this code

```
read -p "Say hello? ";
if  [ $REPLY == "y" ]
then
         echo "Hello"
fi
```

I want this (<--tab--> represents one tab character(\t))

```
read -p "Say hello? ";
if  [ $REPLY == "y" ]
then
<--tab--> echo "Hello"
fi
```

Not this (\s represents one blank space character)

```
read -p "Say hello? ";
if  [ $REPLY == "y" ]
then
\s\s\s\s\s echo "Hello"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copy-pasting code with the mouse in a terminal, you will always copy spaces.

The solution is to use vim's copy-and-paste mechanism:

1. Open file one

   ```
   vim file1.txt
   ```
2. Go the the line `read ...`
3. Type `5yy` (copy 5 lines)
4. Type `:open file2.txt` to open the other file
5. Move the cursor to the line above where you want to paste
6. Type `p` (to paste)

Answer (score 2):

Are there tabs in your clipboard?   If you're pasting spaces and you want them to turn into tabs, you can just do `:retab`

Comment: Apparently thats not an option in my vim

Comment: It's a command, not an option, i.e., It's `:retab`, *not* `:set retab`